# Question about networks and connections from pc to servers

Tags: sockets, browser, python-requests

Please let me know if this question is not appropriate for this medium. However, I have been trying to get an answer to this seemingly unanswerable question for quite some time. When dealing with connection to a server/website, I noticed that you either have to use programming language like python, burpsuite, or a browser. However, when I tried to understand how those aforementioned softwares work on a fundamental level, I could not find any answers. It seems there is a complex system that is required to connect to a another network. Is there a way to understand this on a fundamental level?

I'm not talking about macro networking concepts, I am talking about : "what is the computer doing when the information is sent?" What system is being utilized to convert my requests from python to its destination? Is it machine code? I am having a hard time asking this question, perhaps because I know too little, but I hope someone will know the answer:)

Other questions include, why can't you change a header response in the browser, but you can change it in python or burpsuite?

Thank you so much community!

I have tried googling for hours to no avail. No text book i have downloaded from libgen.is has the answer either.

Comment: There are browser plugins that let you change headers. This question requires an answer that is tutorial in nature. Stackoverflow is not really designed to work that way.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But is there a resource that would be good to understand these things? I can use the tools, I just want to go deeper in understanding the fundamentals.